# Can the xflock screen be changed or customized?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, lock-screen

I don't like the look of the xflock screen from Xubuntu.

I was wondering if there is a way to personalize it or substitute it with other lock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xflock4 is just a script that tries to guess what locking options are available.

It will try gnome-screensaver (THE GOOD), xscreensaver (THE BAD), xlock (THE UGLY).

Hopefully, lightdm will take over locking in the next ubuntu release.